# SFML Animation playing only one frame

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to get my animation to cycle through three images when a key is pressed. Currently it switches image only if key pressed. Else way it is not seemed on screen. I have tried to update my animation but it causes the animation to get stuck in one place.
Could anyone explain to me how to go about implementing this please?

*Animation.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Sprite.hpp>
class Animation
{
    bool reversed;

    
    unsigned short animation_iterator;
    unsigned short animation_speed;
    unsigned short current_frame;
    unsigned short frame_width;
    unsigned short total_frames;

    sf::Sprite sprite;

    sf::Texture texture;
public:
    Animation(const unsigned short i_frame_width, const std::string& i_texture_location, const unsigned short i_animation_speed = 1);

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& i_window);
    void set_animation_speed(const unsigned short i_animation_speed);
    void set_reversed(const bool i_value);
    void set_position(const short i_x, const short i_y);
    void set_texture_location(const std::string& i_texture_location);
    void update();
};
Animation::Animation(const unsigned short i_frame_width, const std::string& i_texture_location, const unsigned short i_animation_speed) :
    reversed(0),
    animation_iterator(0),
    animation_speed(0),
    current_frame(0),
    frame_width(i_frame_width)
{
    texture.loadFromFile(i_texture_location);

    total_frames = texture.getSize().x / frame_width;
}

void Animation::draw(sf::RenderWindow& i_window)
{
    sprite.setTexture(texture);

    if (0 == reversed)
    {
        sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(current_frame * frame_width, 0, frame_width, texture.getSize().y));
    }
    else
    {
    
        sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(frame_width * (1 + current_frame), 0, -frame_width, texture.getSize().y));
    }

    i_window.draw(sprite);
}

void Animation::set_animation_speed(const unsigned short i_animation_speed)
{
    animation_speed =  i_animation_speed;
}

void Animation::set_reversed(const bool i_value)
{
    reversed = i_value;
}

void Animation::set_position(const short i_x, const short i_y)
{
    sprite.setPosition(i_x, i_y);
}

void Animation::set_texture_location(const std::string& i_texture_location)
{
    texture.loadFromFile(i_texture_location);
}

void Animation::update()
{
    while (animation_iterator >= animation_speed)
    {
        animation_iterator -= animation_speed;

        current_frame = (1 + current_frame) % total_frames;
    }

    animation_iterator++;
}
```

*Hero.h*

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Animation.h"
int CELL_SIZE = 85;
class Hero {
    bool crouching=0;
    bool dead=0;
    bool reversed=0;
    bool on_ground=0;
    float horizontal_speed;
    float vertical_speed;
    float x=0;
    float y=0;
    unsigned char jump_timer=0;//при зажатии кнопки прыжка персонаж прыгает выше
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Texture texture;
    Animation walk_animation = Animation(CELL_SIZE, "Resources/Images/Hero_Walk.png", 1);
public:
    Hero() {
        texture.loadFromFile("Resources/Images/Hero_Idle.png");
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
    }
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& i_window) {
        sprite.setPosition(round(x), round(y));
        i_window.draw(sprite);
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {
            sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, texture.getSize().x, texture.getSize().y));
            walk_animation.set_position(round(x), round(y));
            
            walk_animation.draw(i_window);
        
            
        }

    }
```

I have tried to increase the counter of the current frame but that makes the animation disappear from the screen, also trying to refresh the sprite screen clears everything completely

Comment: From what I can see, you never call the `update` function part of the `Animation` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the right arrow is pressed you should cycle between `draw` and `update`. This way after every frame is drawn the next will be ready. the fix should be easy: just append a call to `update` after the `draw` call. Then the next time you'll enter this function, assuming you have an event polling loop, the next animation should be drawn.